# How do you counter multi-tank teams in Dominion?

Tags: league-of-legends

In Dominion, characters that can just stick around towers and toss ranged attacks but still have a fair bit of defense (Kayle, Galio) seem to be able to indefinitely buy time against 2 or even 3 attackers until backup arrives, which is never far away due to free speed buffs in the center.  The extreme mobility also allows the defense-y classes to rush between CPs.

How do you counter a team that goes heavy into tanks?

Comment: That doesn't sound like trouble with multi-tank teams - if they're holding out till backup arrives, your problem is their teamwork, not their tankiness.

Comment: I would say leave them and go cap another tower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they have a lot of HP, have your ranged champion(s) shred away at it with Kitae's Bloodrazor ( deals 2.5% of the target's maximum HP as magic damage -- basically, it's a weaker version of Madred's Bloodrazor.  more info here: http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/kitaes-bloodrazor-128 ).  This should be purchased by a ranged champion with a high attack speed.  Hit-and-run harass them until they're too low to defend (or until you can score a kill on them).

Kog'Maw would also be an effective counter, especially with Kitae's Bloodrazor, since his W skill is essentially a Bloodrazor in itself, and because his longer range (and great synergy with items like Frozen Mallet) will allow him to harass even harder.  And it goes without saying, but his ultimate is another great way to chip away at / drive out those champions who like to camp at their turrets (also note that his ultimate is great for defending as well, since a single hit from far away will stop a capture).

Comment: Madred's does 2.5% damage also.

Comment: Isn't it 4%?  http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/madreds-bloodrazor-89

Comment: Madreds is 4%.  The other reason Kog is such a good "Bloodrazor platform" is that he inherently does a lot of magic damage (all of his abilities).  That means that you can eschew the typical "AD/Armor pen" route and go Magic Damage on hit/Void Staff.

Comment: In recent games, while the bonus damage is significantly nice, I've found that the extra range aspect of Kog'Maw's Bio-Arcane Barrage is *immensely* helpful in bashing tanks who are just dawdling on the platform. You can hit pretty far into there while staying safely outside the turret range.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips on how to counter a tank defending a turret :

- Be 2 or 3
- Use the garnison summoner spell on the turret to considerably reduce its damage (80% damage reduction)
- Have a minion wave pushing with you. Minions capture towers very quickly (you can even use the promote summoner spell), occupy the tank while minions capture the turret
- Capture another point

If you don't have a minion wave with you, you are alone and don't have the garnison summoner spell :

- go fight with your team and come back when tank is pushing to your turret (meaning away from his)
- create a minion wave by farming on the lane (harrass tank if he leaves his turret)
- Go and get central buff
- go backdoor a lonely point (although I don't like this option, better go with team to gank and/or capture another point)

The thing about tanks is they defend well, but it's also very easy to defend against them (as they don't do much damage) making your turret is also pretty safe. So make him leave his turret, outnumber / overpower him or go somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the game is blind pick, so you never know if you're up against a tank heavy team or not.  The answer to this question is fairly simple:

- Kill them.

If you're having trouble with that, here's some ways to make it easier:

- Use the new summoner spells.  A wave of minions led by a super minion will knock the turret to neutral.  Garrison will reduce the turret's damage significantly.
- Gang up.  More allies equals an easier kill.
- Grab the center buff.
- Lay a trap.  Leave the turret closest to the tank undefended; if he pushes out, gank him.  If he doesn't, go win your 5v4 teamfight.
- Pick a tanky dps.  Jax comes to mind..
- Pick a ranged dps that you know can shred a tank.  Teemo, cait, vayne all come to mind.

If a tank is just sitting at a tower, use his static position to your advantage.  It's rarely necessary to engage him at his tower.

Answer (score 0):

In Dominion the best way to counter an overly tanky team that is content to just sit and defend bases is to split off and cap alternate points. By doing this you force the champions off the turrets and are free to engage them in the lane or jungle of the map. As far as taking down overly tanky champions building items like Void Staff and Last Whisper allow you to shred through their Magic Resist and Armor.